# Recover complex number from several noised components.

Tags: complex-numbers, noise

I know these 12 values, which are derivative from the same unknown complex variable `z`:

```
re1  := noise(Re(z), N1);
re2  := noise(Re(z), N2);
re3  := noise(Re(z), N3);
im1  := noise(Im(z), N1);
im2  := noise(Im(z), N4);
im3  := noise(Im(z), N5);
mod1 := noise(|z|, N2);
mod2 := noise(|z|, N4);
mod3 := noise(|z|, N6);
arg1 := noise(Arg(Z), N3);
arg2 := noise(Arg(Z), N5);
arg3 := noise(Arg(Z), N6);
```

`N1..N6` are also known, and are real variables calculated from attendant data.

`noise` function is abstract "distortion function", that takes real argument and returns its noised version, where amount of noise is proportional to second argument. I have declared it for modelling as following:

```
noise(v, n) := v * (1 + uniform(-n, n)) + uniform(-n, n)
```

But in real usage, nature of noise will be hardly determinable, as `re*`, `im*`, `mod*` and `arg*` values come already noised from outer world - I know only the abstract value of measure of distortion.

I have to find `z` from given values of `N*` and `re*`, `im*`, `mod*` and `arg*` with smallest possible error.

For the case of `N1=N2=N3=N4=N5=N6` I've empirically found these formulas (in order of decreasing error) to provide better results, than straightforward decoding using any of re-im-mod-arg pairs:

```
Z1 := from_re_im((re1 + re2 + re3) / 3, (im1 + im2 + im3) / 3);
Z2 := from_mod_arg((mod1 + mod2 + mod3) / 3, (arg1 + arg2 + arg3) / 3);
Z3 := from_re_im((re1 + re2 + re3 + Re(Z2)) / 4, (im1 + im2 + im3 + Im(Z2)) / 4);
Z4 := from_mod_arg((mod1 + mod2 + mod3 + |Z1|) / 4, (arg1 + arg2 + arg3 + Arg(Z1)) / 4);
```

Utility functions mentioned above:

```
from_re_im(re, im) := re + im * 1i;
from_mod_arg(mod, arg) := mod * cos(arg) + mod * sin(arg) * 1i;
```

Unfortunately, when noise coefficients become unbalanced, Z4 becomes suboptimal. For example, increasing N6 among others significantly raises Z4's error, and it becomes less optimal than Z1.

So, my question is - **Is there way to reliably recover `z` from present information with smallest possible error, without need to repeatedly rerequest data (noised different way)?**

Thanks in advance.